# Recursively convert nested arrays to nested objects using object's keys for each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object, data-structures

I'd like to change this data structure:

```
[ { sectionName: 'SectionOne',
    ingredients: [ {ingredient: 'sugar'}, {ingredient: 'flour'} ]},
  { sectionName: 'SectionTwo',
    ingredients: [ {ingredient: 'eggs'}, {ingredient: 'water'} ] },
 ]
```

to this:

```
{ SectionOne:
       { sectionName: 'SectionOne',
         ingredients: {
           sugar: { ingredient: 'sugar' },
           flour: { ingredient: 'flour' }
          }
        },
{ SectionTwo:
       { sectionName: 'SectionTwo',
         ingredients: {
           eggs: { ingredient: 'eggs' },
           water: { ingredient: 'water' }
          }
        },

 }
```

In other words, I'd like to use use the object's keys for each array that I want to convert to an object.

You can find an example of the data structure on this
[jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankydep/vx4Ls8e4/)
 together with mine attempt.

So far, using lodash or vanillaJS I've only been able to convert the outer array.
I couldn't manage to recursively use _.mapKeys(), for loops or similar to get to the desired structure. I'm sure I'm missing a silly point but I couldn't get around this.

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` an array and construct your objects pretty straighforward:

```js
const data = [ 
  { sectionName: 'SectionOne',
    ingredients: [ {ingredient: 'sugar'}, {ingredient: 'flour'} ]},
  { sectionName: 'SectionTwo',
    ingredients: [ {ingredient: 'eggs'}, {ingredient: 'water'} ] },
 ];
 
const res = Object.assign(...data.map(el => ({ // for every element
  [el.sectionName]: {
    sectionName: el.sectionName,
    ingredients: Object.assign(...el.ingredients.map(e => ({[e.ingredient]: e}))) // assign each object inside array
    }
  })))

console.log(res)
console.log(res.SectionOne.ingredients.sugar)
```

Here `[something]` notation creates a key, which name is a value of `something` variable. Three dots `...` spread an array into separate elements, like if these elements where just separated by comma.

Comment: That's a very concise syntax. It works, but `data.map()` will wrap everything in an array. Say, I still can't call `res.sectionOne.ingredients.sugar`. Maybe iterating with a `for..of loop` or `for` loop will do?

Comment: @frankydep I edited my answer. Now it creates an object where you can access your props with `res.sectionOne.ingredients.sugar`. At first I didn't realize you need a final result to be an object.

Comment: wostex! Very nice work! I can't still get my mind around why `.map()` in the context of `Object.assing()` is not generating an array. Is it because of the spread operator? Also Should `Object.assing()` require a target object? Thanks again!

Comment: @frankydep `data.map` creates an array of objects, which get `spread` with `...` into this: `Object.assign({first data object}, {second data object}, etc)`. Also, try `Object.assign({a: 1})` in your console - it works fine, creates your object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution here using reduce. You might be able to refactor this more:

```
const sections = [
  { sectionName: 'SectionOne',
    ingredients:
      [
        {ingredient: 'sugar'},
        {ingredient: 'flour'}
      ]
  },
  { sectionName: 'SectionTwo',
    ingredients:
      [
        {ingredient: 'eggs'}, {ingredient: 'water'}
      ]
  },
];

const result = sections.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const ingredientsObj = currentValue.ingredients.reduce((acc, ingredient) => {
    acc[ingredient.ingredient] = {
      ingredient: ingredient.ingredient
    };
    return acc;
  }, {});

  var sectionObject = {
    sectionName: currentValue.sectionName,
    ingredients: ingredientsObj
  }
  accumulator[currentValue.sectionName] = sectionObject;
  return accumulator;

}, {});

console.log(result);
```